# How to use "contains" function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my Excel table with 3 input columns. The last column is the output column with the result I need.

[Excel Input and Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAHWL.png)

Here is the sample macro I have:

```
Function month(x As string, y As string, z As String) As String

If (((x = "January.Winter") Or (y = "January.Winter")) And (z = "jan")) Then
    month= "true"

Else If (((x = "January.2016") Or (y = "January.2016")) And (z = "jan")) Then
    month= "true" 

Else If (((x = "January.today") Or (y = "January.today")) And (z = "jan")) Then
    month= "true"    

Else
    month= False
End If
End Function
```

My worksheet contains thousands of rows which includes "january" as a substring as a text in the cells. Instead of writing multiple checks like "if "x=January.winter"", I would like to use simplify the macro by checking if the string "x" or string "y" contains the string "January". Is there a way I could change the macro to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three ways that spring to mind:

```
If LCase$(x) Like "january*" Or LCase$(y) Like "january*" Then
    ...


If InStr(LCase$(x), "january") Or InStr(LCase$(x), "january") Then
    ...


If LCase$(Left$(x, 7)) = "january" Or LCase$(Left$(y, 7)) = "january" Then
    ...
```

It really just depends how inventive you want to get.

---

Note that I've used `LCase$()` to force text to lower case and prevent any issues with capitilisation - always something worth thinking about when comparing strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the InStr function. Example use:

```
If (InStr(x,"January") > 0 Or InStr(y,"January")>0) And (z = "Jan") Then
 ...
```

It returns 0 if your substring isn't found, otherwise it returns the position of your substring.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)

Also careful with upper and lower casing. "January" will not match "january". Use LCase and UCase functions to force upper or lower casing, as Macro Man did in his answer.